# Functions and algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Q4)

$f(x) = x^2 +4kx + (3+11k)$ where $k$ is a constant

i) Express $f(x)$ in the form $(x+p)^2 +q$, where $p$ and $q$ are constants to be found in terms of $k$.

Given that the equation $f(x)=0$ has no real roots

ii) Find the set of all possible values of $k$.

---

So for i)

Thus far I have:

$f(x) = x^2 +4kx + (3+11k)$

$(x+2k)^2 + 4k^2 + (3+11k)$

$f(x) = (x+2k)^2 + 3 + 11k + 4k^2 $

---

ii) I've got some working which is too complicated to type out but I've ended up with k is smaller than or equal to $0.92$.

Clearly I need $4$ answers. Have I gone wrong, where could I go from here? What is the smartest way to work out both parts of the question?

Many thanks all

S

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you have a wrong sign:
$$
f(x) = x^2 +4kx + (3+11k)=x^2 +4kx +4k^2
\mathbin{\color{red}{-}}4k^2
 + (3+11k)
$$
so you get
$$
f(x)=(x+2k)-4k^2+11k+3
$$

You don't need step 1 to solve step 2. A degree two polynomial has no real roots if and only if its discriminant is negative:
$$
(4k)^2-4(3+11k)<0
$$
becomes
$$
16k^2-12-44k<0
$$
or
$$
4k^2-11k-3<0
$$
Now, the roots of $4k^2-11k-3=0$ are $-1/4$ and $3$, so…

Comment: May I ask where you established those roots from?

-1
-4
and 3

Comment: So the answer is minus a quarter and positive 3!

Comment: @Icomefromalanddownunder No: $-1/4<k<3$

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step:

$$f(x)=x^2+4xk+3+11k$$

if you add and substract $4k^2$ you get:

$$f(x)=x^2+4xk+4k^2-4k^2+3+11k=(x+2k)^2-4k^2+11k+3$$

If we call $p=2k$ and $q=-4k^2+11k+3$ we've written the function in the form $f(x)=(x+p)^2+q$.

Now we know $f(x)=0$ has no real roots. That means

$$(x+p)^2+q=0\Leftrightarrow(x+p)^2=-q$$

has no real roots. Thus $q$ must be positive. That is $q=-4k^2+11k+3>0$. Can you calculate the values of $k$ that fulfill  $-4k^2+11k+3>0$?

Comment: Do I need to solve the inequality for k first, by moving k across?

Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: You solve the inequality for $k$. Try it first. In case you get stuck, 
solve the quadratic equation: $-4k^2+11k+3=0$. You get $k=\frac{-1}{4}$ and $k=3$. Then split the real line in three parts: $(-\infty,\frac{-1}{4})$, $(\frac{-1}{4},3)$, $(3,\infty)$. On which of these intervals is the expression $-4k^2+11k+3$ positive? (just pick a value for $k$ within each of the three intervals and plug it into the expression to  find out its sign on the corresponding interval.

You'll find that $-4k^2+11k+3>0$ if $k\in(-\frac{1}{4},3)$.

Comment: Thank you this is grand.

So there are two values for k which fulfill the requirements of the problem, 
minus a quarter and positive 3?

Comment: Nope! All the range of values between $\frac{-1}{4}$ and $3$ fulfill the requirements. Actually $\frac{-1}{4}$ and $3$ are excluded!

Comment: Ahh! I'm getting there gradually, I understood everything until that last point! Thanks so much to the both of you, you're stars.